# SqlAlchemy unable to set attribute on unmapped subclass

Tags: python, sqlite, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I have an inheritance hierarchy that looks like the following:

```
Fruits
   Apples (has type='apple')
      GrannySmith (has type='grannysmith')
      Rotten (does not have a mapping defined)
```

When instantiating something of type `Rotten` and attempting to set an attribute that has a column in apple, I see the below error:

```
File ".../sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 228, in __set__
    self.impl.set(instance_state(instance),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'
```

I'm not sure why this is the case, but if I do map `Rotten` to a type, I no longer see this issue. Any idea why I must map a class?

I'd like to be able to subclass classes whose parents might happen to be mapped to a table, but not require the subclass to have any database interaction.

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/funseiki/72c8b8cdd5e39b97385ce638de887fa1) for an example that displays the exception at the final line.